# Does defender link in to client-server connections?

Tags: windows, antivirus, windows-defender, endpoint-for-defender

I have a client-server application. A listener is running on the server and is contacted by the clients on a specific port.

We are moving from cybereason to defender right now.

When we activate defender most of the RPC calls from our clients to the server fail. It happens with cybereason, too, but only every now and then.

My question is: Does defender link in between the listener and the clients? Or is there some other way defender might cause this behaviour?